# several gmail mails - not seen all addresses

Tags: gmail

Is there any solution for this problem  - in sent messages, which contain correspondence of several mails, often there is no list of all addresses to whom these mails below were sent?

Answer (score -1):

MY facebook account HAS been hacked[image]